# NSKeyedUnarchiver does not call initWithCoder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've used the following example:

[game state singleton cocos2d, initWithEncoder always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670815/game-state-singleton-cocos2d-initwithencoder-always-returns-null)

Instead of using a file, I use an NSData object i am getting from NSUserDefaults.  It is not null, but rather have data in it that I believe is the correctly encoded data and for some reason when I run unarchiveObjectWithData it does not call initWithCoder as I put an NSLog on the first line.

Ideas?

```
+ (void)loadState {
 @synchronized([AppStateManager class]) {
  if (!sharedAppStateManager) {
   [AppStateManager sharedManager];
  }

  NSUserDefaults *udefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSData *archivedData = [udefs objectForKey:@"AppState"];
  NSLog(@"going to unarchive");
  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedData];
  NSLog(@"unarchive complete");
 }
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
 NSLog(@"init coder");
 self = [super init];
 if (self != nil) {
  [self setUsername:[decoder decodeObjectWithKey:@"username"]];
 }

 return self;
}
```

Comment: Does the unarchiver throw an exception? If not, does it return an object? If it does return an object, what class is it?

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

The example posted at the link above initializes the object via "sharedInstance" using the allocWithZone method.  If the object exists it returns nil.

the NSKeyedUnarchiver tries to alloc AGAIN via allocWithZone and since the object has already been initialized earlier in that very same method, or sometimes before hand the unarchiver gets a nil instead of an allocated object.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is probably my issue, so thanks. Will stick to encode and decode.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, but after I do this to obtain my `NSData` of the archive (the contents of which i think is inconsequential):

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *encodedConfig = [userDefaults valueForKey:kConfiguration];
```

When I execute this, it returns `nil`.

```
NSArray *configs = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedConfig];
```

But when I execute this, I get the expected, previously archived, array of objects.

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:encodedConfig];
NSArray *configs = [unarchiver decodeObject];
```

I expect identical behavior from these two approaches.  My only response is avoid `unarchiveObjectWithData:`.

Comment: you are correct sir, there is definitely a problem with the unarchiveObjectWithData returning anything but a nil... and when I use the initForReadingWithData it works...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much an answer but a bit of additional info I found while trying to work a similar issue out. I guess I am still under rookie status, so this is the only way I could find to contribute to this post.

Anyways...
Thanks so much for banging through this issue...especially over here:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/11327

I was having a problem with a mutable array working using the method you had worked out where it would switch to an immutable array after I unarchived it from the file.

Casting the returned array as a mutable version did not work either.
I end up adding objectsFromArray to my mutable array and this solved my problems.

Worked:

```
[self.mutableArray addObjectsFromArray:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"MutableArray"]];
```

Neither of these worked:

```
self.mutableArray = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"MutableArray"];

self.mutableArray = (NSMutableArray *)[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"MutableArray"];
```

Comment: an aside: fyi (since you mentioned being a rookie) the cast to `NSMutableArray` will not change the code that is executed, it will only effect any type warnings the compiler might issue.